# Powershell: Get number of computers connected to Active Directory by OS

Tags: powershell, group-by, active-directory, operating-system

I have a task to get the number of computers connected to a certain Active Directory, grouped by OS.
I figured out how to find out the name of the OS installed on a certain computer:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OperatingSystem
```

I am having a hard time understanding, how should I group and then count the different kind of operating system in powershell.  Also in the testing enviroment I got set up, I only have one computer connected to the AD, so I really don't have room to test out my ideas. I have requested some additional virtual machines to be connected to the AD, but I would like to figure the how until I get those.

Comment: Look into the Group-Object cmdlet

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments by @Scepticalist - `Group-Object` is the tool designed for this specific purpose.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem | group-object OperatingSystem | select name,count
```

Answer (score 0):

#### All Windows Servers

Get-ADComputer -Filter {operatingsystem -like '*server*'} -Properties Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address,lastlogondate | Export-Csv c:\temp\WinServers6.csv

#### All Windows clients

Get-ADComputer -Filter {operatingsystem -notlike '*server*'} -Properties Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address,lastlogondate | Export-Csv c:\temp\WinClients.csv

#### All Computers in AD

Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address

Comment: that looks likely ... but you _really_ should wrap your code in code formatting. the asterisks in your `-like` targets are not showing up since you didn't properly wrap the code in code formatting. [*grin*]